# display answer in an maths game in Android

Tags: android

In my game i have a hash button which acts like a submit button. when i press the hash button it displays INCORRECT even if the answer is correct, Do i have to add a different if statement for each position in  the array? It displays INCORRECT each expression.

(Sorry i'm a new in this)

```
package com.gamesup.braingame;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Easy extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText display;
// This Array says , I am an array that holds arrays
String [][] multiArray = {{"4 + 5", "9"},     
        {"20 * 3","60"},
        {"99 - 9","90"}};  
TextView displayExpression;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.easy);

    display = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.displayText);
    display.setText("?");

    displayExpression = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expression);
    Button generate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.random_gen);

    generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random ranGenerate = new Random ();
            int random = ranGenerate.nextInt(multiArray.length) ;
            // Fetch your random question
            String Rquestion = multiArray[random][0];
            displayExpression.setText(Rquestion);


        }
    });

}

static boolean isEmpty = true;

public void num_Clicked(View v){
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(v.getId());
    //getting the button object and using a view to get the id of the buttons

     if (v.getId()== R.id.del_button){
            String s = display.getText().toString();
            s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
            display.setText(s);
            return;
     }


    if(isEmpty){
        display.setText(btn.getText());
        isEmpty = false;
    }
    else{
        display.append(btn.getText().toString()); 



}

public void hash_Clicked(View v){

    if (v.getId()== R.id.hash_button){


         // Get the Answer from your EditText
         String answer =  display.getText().toString();

         // Using a for loop iterate on the base index
         for(int i = 0; i < multiArray.length ; i++)
         {
              // if the answer is in position 1 of Array [i] 
              if(answer.equals(multiArray[i][1]))
              {
                // We have found the answer, Congratulate the User 
                  displayExpression.setText("CORRECT");

              }else{
                  // Tell them how bad they are since they can't solve simple equations!
                  displayExpression.setText("INCORRECT");

              }



         }

    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `break` statement after you show that the answer is correct, so that you don't iterate through the remaining answers in your array and compare with current, because if you have a correct answer at say index 0, you are still going through the remaining answers in an array, so your "CORRECT" gets replaced by "INCORRECT".

```
// if the answer is in position 1 of Array [i] 
if(answer.equals(multiArray[i][1]))
{
    // We have found the answer, Congratulate the User 
    displayExpression.setText("CORRECT");

    break; //<---add this to exit the loop, because correct answer has been found
}
```